# Groovie Gorilla and GPIO

Tags: .net-core, raspberry-pi, ubuntu-20.10

I want to use RaspberryIO library with dotnet core version 3.1 on Ubuntu 20.10.
When it comes to use

```
Pi.Init<BootstrapWiringPi>();
```

I got error:

```
Unhandled exception. System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load shared library 'libwiringPi.so.2.52' or one of its dependencies. In order to help diagnose loading problems, consider setting the LD_DEBUG environment variable: liblibwiringPi.so.2.52: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

The same code works perfectly on Raspbian.

I use:
Raspberry Pi 4

Comment: Please add a tag for the programming language you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case (Rpi3 + Ubuntu 20.04 x64 + dotnet core 3.1):

1. clone https://github.com/WiringPi/WiringPi
2. build
3. copy libwiringPi.so.2.60 and gpio to app folder
4. rename libwiringPi.so.2.60 to libwiringPi.so.2.52

and Pi.Init < BootstrapWiringPi >( );
with TestLedBlinking() is work.